# Rails retrieving all records in show controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

In my rails category show controller for categories I have it setup like this

```
def show
    @categories = Category.find_by(params[:name])
  end
```

But when I visit this controller it returns all records of products found in the category instead of single category.

Here is the code in my view controller for category

```
<div class="grid">
    <% @categories.products.each do |product|  %>

    <%= link_to product_path(id: product.slug, category_name: product.category.name), class: "card" do %>
<div class="product-image">
<%= image_tag product.productpic.url if product.productpic? %>
    </div>

      <div class="product-text">
        <h2 class="product-title"> <%= product.name %></h2>
          <h3 class="product-price">£<%= product.price %></h3>
      </div>

        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You've explained what is happening but what is *supposed* to happen?

Comment: #find_by should only return one record, so it should be @category. In any case, what is @categories?

Comment: Can you show your relationships declaration? I don't think the problem is in controller..

Comment: Except by name of variables, it seems alright here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for security purposes, you should never trust the params hash to retrieve records. Rails will "make the data safe" if you use a hash as your arguments. Use this code below:

```
def show
  @category = Category.find_by(name: params[:name])
end
```

Second, usually on a show page, you only want to retrieve one record and therefore the variable should be named as singular. I corrected that above.

Third, it helps if you use proper indenting when posting examples. It makes it easier for us to help you.

Fourth, the line below (I changed `@categories` to `@category`) is basically saying: "Now that I have this *single* category, find **all** the products associated with it in the `products` table and put them into the `|product|` variable for iteration"

```
<% @category.products.each do |product|  %>
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the category, but if you keep this line of code, it will always show you all the products. Maybe you only want to show the most recent 3, in which case you could do something like this:

In your controller:

```
def show
  @category = Category.find_by(name: params[:name])
  @recent_products = @category.products.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)
end
```

In your view:

```
<div class="grid">
  <% @recent_products.each do |product|  %>
    <%= link_to product_path(id: product.slug, category_name: product.category.name), class: "card" do %>
      <div class="product-image">
        <%= image_tag product.productpic.url if product.productpic? %>
      </div>
      <div class="product-text">
        <h2 class="product-title"> <%= product.name %></h2>
        <h3 class="product-price">£<%= product.price %></h3>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way
in your controller you can write this code

```
def show
 @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:name])
end
```

and in your view it will work

```
<div class="grid">
  <% @category.products.each do |product|%>
    // place your code what you want to display
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I hope it would help you and still if you have any concern please let me know.